# Quick way to approximate a truncated gaussian distribution?

Tags: mathematics, procedural-generation, random, statistics

I'm doing some procgen stuff and I need a truncated gaussian distribution. Basically, I need a way to get the same thing as this:

```
import random
def truncated_gaussian(mean, deviation, min, max):
    while True:
        val = random.gauss(mean, deviation)
        if min < val < max: return val
```

except without so much wasted effort. It looks like this is a pretty complicated thing to do *properly*, but I don't need statistics-grade perfect randomness, just a video-game-grade approximation.

Anyone know a trick to make this work?

Comment: You might also be able to do this via inverse transform sampling, re-scaling the CDF to your desired range and clamping it before sampling the resulting function's inverse. I think you'd want to approximate it as a spline since it's not expressible in elementary functions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When all else fails, cheat. You could either generate 10,000 (or 1,000,000 or whatever) Gaussian randoms at startup, or put them in a resource and load them at start up, then generate one random offset into the list and start reading them as needed. Then it would be as fast as a look-up.

Comment: Oh, of course! And then if I run out it should work to just re-use the same values over and over again if there's enough of them.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. You can index into the array using a modulus operator. Like if it's called `nextIndex` you could grab the next random number by doing `foo = randoms [ nextIndex ]; nextIndex = (nextIndex + 1) % kNumRandoms;`